# edit text style object in mapbasic

Tags: mapbasic

I have created a text object, but then I want to change this object (front and size, ....).

Example: I have created a text object is "Memory" the front is "news Roman Times" and the size is 12. I want to change this object to "Future" to the front is "Arial" and size 15. Could you show me how to do it?
I found some written material that was not done. Is that right?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Sorry everyone for my not clear question. I have edited and hope you help me again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Alter Object statement in the MapBasic help system.

You need to change the Info using the OBJ_INFO_TEXTFONT object_info_code:

```
Alter Object oMemory
   Info OBJ_INFO_TEXTFONT, MakeFont("Arial",0,15,0)
```

Note that in the statement above oMemory is the name of your Object variable